# Creating a TFS branch with same initial code base as second branch

Tags: tfs

Here is my current setup. (TFS2008)

I have a TRUNK with latest.
I have BRANCH-A off of TRUNK with only the production ready code merged in.
I would like to create a new BRANCH-B off of TRUNK but I don't want all the latest code, I only want what is currently in BRANCH-A.

After this is done I will be merging into both BRANCH-A and BRANCH-B from the TRUNK (so I don't want to branch BRANCH-B off of BRANCH-A.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a baseless merge. This sibling situation that you want to achieve is exactly what is described in [How To: Perform a Baseless Merge in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx):

> The process of merging items that are not directly branched from each
>   other is called a baseless merge. For example, you might want to **merge
>   a change between two release branches, which are siblings** of each
>   other, without merging up to the parent branch. You can only perform a
>   baseless merge by using the Tf merge command. You cannot perform a
>   baseless merge from within the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> When you perform a baseless merge, **TFS does not have any information
>   about the relationship of the files in the branches. For example, if
>   you have renamed a file, this will be viewed as a deleted file and a
>   new file will be added in the branch**. For this reason you have to
>   perform more manual conflict resolutions than when you perform a
>   normal merge. However, you only have to perform this conflict
>   resolution once. After you have performed the baseless merge, TFS
>   records merge history and establishes a relationship between the
>   folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

When you create BRANCH-B, you can either choose latest or a specific date/changeset/label.  Take a look when you created BRANCH-A and create the BRANCH-B from the same date/changeset/label.  As long as you haven't made any changes to BRANCH-A, you can create B to match.

Also, if you haven't already, take a look at the [TFS 2008 Branching guidance](http://tfsbranchingguideii.codeplex.com/).  There is some great information and uses a pragmatic approach.

Comment: Yes but BRANCH-A does not have a contiguous set of changes from TRUNK that can resolve to a date or changeset. Different projects within TRUNK may have merged in a changeset here and there.

Comment: Are the merges to BRANCH-A selective or everything?  If everything, basically you should still be able to look in your history of the TRUNK and see when the last time you merged with BRANCH-A and then get that version of the TRUNK.  Would this work for you?

Comment: I have not tried this before, but you could create the BRANCH-B from the trunk (and pick from any time period).  Then do a baseless merge from A to B.  I think this has to be done from command line.

Comment: The baseless merge from A to B might work. I'm just not sure how the subsequent merges from TRUNK to B will behave

Comment: I'm not sure either.  I'll try this scenario on my test TFS server and see tonight.  I was wondering that too.  It might be ok if you branch the latest from trunk to B. I'll let you know what I found out unless someone else knows for sure.

Comment: "It might be ok if you branch the latest from trunk to B"  The only problem with that is how to get the latest changes back into B when they are production ready. I think TFS thinks they are already merged

Comment: Once you do the baseless merge, you should always up merge back to trunk and then down merge to BRANCH-A.

Answer (score 0):

For TRUNK
On Create Branch you have option as a "Branch from Version" - by default By Latest Version is selected.
Select By changeSet or By Date

Comment: Yes but BRANCH-A does not have a contiguous set of changes from TRUNK that can resolve to a date or changeset. Different projects within TRUNK may have merged in a changeset here and there.